# Atomic Minimum on x86 using OpenMP

Tags: c++, x86, openmp, atomic, minimum

Does OpenMP support an atomic minimum for C++11? If OpenMP has no portable method: Is there some way of doing it using a x86 or amd64 feature?

In the OpenMP specifications I found nothing for C++ but the Fortran version seems to support it. See 2.8.5 of the v3.1 for the details. For C++ it states

> binop is one of +, *, -, /, &, ^, |, <<, or >>.

but for Fortran it states

> intrinsic_procedure_name is one of MAX, MIN, IAND, IOR, or IEOR.

In case you are interested in more context: I am looking for a mutex free method of doing the following:

```
vector<omp_lock_t>lock;
vector<int>val;

#pragma omp parallel
{
  // ...
  int x = ...;
  int y = ...;
  if(y < val[x]){
    omp_set_lock(&lock[x]);
    if(y < val[x])
      val[x] = y;
    omp_unset_lock(&lock[x]);
  }
}
```

I know that you can compute the minimum using a reduce algorithm. I know that there are circumstances where this largely outperforms any atomic minimum approach. However, I also know that this is not the case in my situation.

EDIT: One option that is slightly faster in my case is

```
  int x = ...;
  int y = ...;
  while(y < val[x])
    val[x] = y;
```

but that is no atomic operation.

All the newer GPUs have this feature and I am missing it on the CPU. (See atom_min for OpenCL.)

Comment: Is this C++98 or C++11 ?

Comment: By the way, why is it that atomic-min is faster in your case? I had a similar problem where reduction-min didn't improve performance, so maybe I should try atomic-min.

Comment: @user1071136 I suppose that behind the scene the mutexes do nothing else then a spin loop. Coding it directly probably allows for the compiler to produce better code and thus it is faster. This however obviously depends on the particular OpenMP implementation (and on top of it is pure speculation on my part). I am actually pretty afraid of too good optimizers that turn while(y < val[x]) val[x] = y; into if(y < val[x]) val[x] = y; because after val[x] = y the condition y < val[x] must "obviously" be false.

Comment: I don't know about OpenMP, but you could do this on x86 using `lock cmpxchg` to write the new value only if the value hasn't changed, and redoing the comparison until it stops changing. Your compiler probably provides an intrinsic for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The OpenMP specification for C++ does not have support for atomic minimum. Neither does C++11.

I am assuming that in your algorithm, `x` can compute to any valid index, regardless of thread.
I would suggest changing your algorithm, so that each thread uses its own `val` array and then do a final reconciliation at the end, which can also be parallelized by index. This will avoid locks and atomics completely and give you the benefit of separating the data for each thread, i.e. no chance for false cache sharing. In other words, it should be faster.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16190078/how-to-atomically-update-a-maximum-value for a C++11 solution; just swap `<` with `>`