# How to atomically update a maximum value?

Tags: c++, c++11, concurrency, atomic, max

In serial code, updating a maximum could be accomplished simply by

```
template<typename T>
void update_maximum(T& maximum_value, T const& value) noexcept
{
  if(value > maximum_value) maximum_value = value;
}
```

However, how should this be done for an `atomic<T>` variable holding the maximum value:

```
template<typename T>
void update_maximum(std::atomic<T>& maximum_value, T const& value) noexcept
{
   // want a lock-free, thread-safe implementation
}
```

Obviously, the code from the serial version doesn't work, as another thread may alter `maximum_value` between the load and the store. Can one use the `compare_exchange` (which compares `==` rather than `>`) to implement this? how?

Note that explicit locks are not allowed (the only lock allowed is that which may come with the implementation of `std::atomic<T>`).

Answer (score 57, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be possible in a single operation, but you can make a loop, that tries to do this, until it finally succeeds or value in atomic variable becomes bigger than `value`:

```
template<typename T>
void update_maximum(std::atomic<T>& maximum_value, T const& value) noexcept
{
    T prev_value = maximum_value;
    while(prev_value < value &&
            !maximum_value.compare_exchange_weak(prev_value, value))
        {}
}
```

Comment: @zch: shouldn't you update `prev_value` inside the loop? Otherwise if the first `compare_exchange_weak` fails, it will always be comparing to a _potentially_ "old" value and may never leave the loop. Am I right?

Comment: @Walter, I think it is, but I didn't stress test it. @André Neves, `compare_exchange_weak` does the updating when it fails - that's why first argument is by non-const reference.

Comment: Article about CAS loops in C++11: http://herbsutter.com/2012/08/31/reader-qa-how-to-write-a-cas-loop-using-stdatomics/

Comment: @AndréNeves - `compare_exchange_weak` updates `prev_value` if the comparison fails.

Comment: @zch, PeteBecker: You are both right. Thanks for the correction!