# Using std::atomic<double> during parallel loop and update if condition meets requirements

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety

Here there is an example code with a std::atomic and a std::for_each. (C++ 17)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <execution>

int main()
{
    constexpr int vec_size = 2000000;
    std::vector<double> numbers(vec_size, 1.0);
    numbers[vec_size / 2] = 2.0;
    std::atomic<double> max_value{ 0.0 };
    std::for_each(std::execution::par_unseq, numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), [&max_value](double s) {
        if (s > max_value)
        {
            max_value = s;
        }
        });
    std::cout << "Max Value: " << std::fixed << max_value;
    return 0;
}
```

The condition could be evaluated by one thread, during that, another thread could update the max_value. How to do that correct?

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16190791/480982) from 2013 and I wonder whether this is available built-in with C++17 or C++20 today.

Comment: The traditional solution would be to use a [mutex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex).

Comment: The chase for the lock-free unicorn fairy results in a failure more often than not. Only a mutex and a lock will guarantee proper synchronization in this case; but the performance would be likely worse than a simple loop in a single execution thread

Comment: `for_each` is not the tool for this job, and the standard library AFAIK doesn't have it.  You can do this yourself though.  Create a loop that creates chucks of your vector (iterator pairs).  Then create a thread for each pair and have the thread do a linear search for the max value.  Once you have the results from all of the threads, do one more linear traversal of those results to get the max of the maxes.  This lets you avoid needing any thread synchronization except for waiting for the results of all threads.

Comment: @NathanOliver: I guess that the simplification of the code into a [mre] has accidentally produced code which could now be replaced by [max_element](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element), but the actual problem is slightly different and for_each might be a good choice.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/parallelism/existing

Comment: @ThomasWeller Woot.  I forgot about `max_element`, I looked up `max` and saw it wasn't parallelized, forgot there was an algorithm version.

Comment: [compare_exchange](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/compare_exchange) looks close, but only seems to compare for equality/inequality, not for greater.

Comment: In 2012 [Herb Sutter wrote](https://herbsutter.com/2012/08/31/reader-qa-how-to-write-a-cas-loop-using-stdatomics/) that there is no such thing and he implemented it himself.

Answer (score 0):

You can do non-blocking busy wait to update `max_value` from multiple threads without race conditions:

```
// ...
#include <emmintrin.h>

int main() {
    // ...
    std::atomic<double> max_value{ 0.0 };
    auto const update_max_value = [&max_value](double s) {
        for(double expected = max_value.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
            expected < s && !max_value.compare_exchange_weak(expected, s);)
            _mm_pause(); 
    };
    std::for_each(std::execution::par_unseq, numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), update_max_value);
    // ...
}
```

`compare_exchange_weak` reloads `max_value` into `expected` if `max_value` has changed since it was loaded into `expected`.

---

Updating `max_value` from multiple threads is not necessary for this task, you can find the maximum value in the range using any number threads ([`std::max_element` overloads 2 and 4](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element)) and only then update `max_value`. This way only one thread ever loads and updates `max_value`, so that no `std::atomic` is necessary:

```
double max_value = *std::max_element(std::execution::par_unseq, numbers.begin(), numbers.end());
```