# How to atomically set a new minimum?

Tags: c++

Simple question, but I did not find an answer.

Given

```
struct Foo {
  std::atomic_int i;
  void setMin(int j);
}
```

How do I set `i` to `std::min(i,j)`? If there is a race between two calls `setMin(j1)` and `setMin(j2)`, the result should be `std::min(i,j1,j2)`, and naturally the same for more than 2 concurrent calls.

---

I found [Atomic Minimum on x86 using OpenMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12255266/atomic-minimum-on-x86-using-openmp) which says "[C++11] does not have support for atomic minimum. "

Comment: Generally, anything of the form "atomic = F(atomic)" is implemented via a CAS loop.

Comment: In hindsight I should have searched for "maximum" as well.

Comment: @MSalters well, this duplicate question will lead future readers in the right direction, so it's a net gain!